# Got a 400 error in GitHub page and it's completely blank

Tags: github

I've tried to get my GitHub Pages up, but it's completely blank in my page, and the console errors were almost all about 400.

I've tried to change the homepage URL, but didn't work. Not sure what causes this.

My github page: https://shilibrad.github.io/monsters-rolodex/

https://github.com/shilibrad/monsters-rolodex

Errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
2.8f03cf10.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
main.dd5c26f6.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
2.8f03cf10.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
main.dd5c26f6.chunk.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
shilibrad.github.io/monsters-rolodex/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
manifest.json:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
main.7444030a.chunk.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

Comment: The path were incorrect indeed. Good catch! I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: yee I realized it was just a typo... Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the issue persists:

- there was a [recent incident](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/v8c1s2x3vnbz)
- the GitHub pages just had a feature rollout: "[Build and deploy GitHub Pages from any branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-09-03-build-and-deploy-github-pages-from-any-branch/) "

Both might influences how the HTTP request is perceived by the GitHub server.

Make sure you have

- [configured a publication branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site).
- an `index.html` file to be read by default

As seen in the [latest OP's commit](https://github.com/shilibrad/monsters-rolodex/commit/e76e528f6f861acdd1dec818817a4bf8413fa479#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b), the paths were incorrect:

```
/monster-rolodex/...
# instead of
/monsters-rolodex/
```